# How to set a condition for the first execution of an SP in a SQL Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, jobs

This is the SP that a SQL Job is scheduled to run on a daily basis

```
DECLARE SR_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT RId 
FROM  [Table] SReq
where  SReq.[Status] != 12345
AND (@FirstRun = True  AND [RDate] > DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())) 
OR (@FirstRun = False AND [RDate] > DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()))     
OPEN SReq_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM SR_cursor
```

So for the **@FirstRun** the date is one month old else 7 days

Comment: Can you explain further with examples? What's the actual problem?

Comment: Check current time and If it less than the time of the second execution, execute your procedure with {@FirstRun = true}. Another way you should save the state.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The stored procedure will be attached to SQL job that will run on a daily basis, For it's first run i need to get entries starting from a 1 Month old dates Otherwise for the rest of the executions the entries should be 7 days old only.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin may you please provide more details about saving the state

Comment: @User_KA, for example, create a table with a date field and save to that field each execution date. If current date more than the saved one it is the first run.